# unrelated nested foreach with an outer %dopar% and an inner %do%

Tags: r, foreach, snow, rparallel

I am running tasks locally in parallel using `%dopar%` from the `foreach` package using the `doSNOW` package to create the cluster (running this on a windows machine at the moment). I have done this many times before and it works fine until I place an unrelated `foreach` loop using a `%do%` (i.e. non-parallel) inside of it. Then R gives me the error (with traceback) :

```
 Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "%do%""  3 stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr))  2 e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)  1 foreach(rc = 1:5) %dopar% {
    aRandomCounter = -1
    if (1 > 0) {
        for (batchi in 1:20) { ...
```

Here is some code that replicates the problem on my machine:

```
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
cl<-makeCluster(5) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
for(stepi in 1:10)  # normal outer for
{
  foreach(rc=1:5) %dopar% # the time consuming stuff in parallel (not looking to actually retrieve any data)
  {
    aRandomCounter = -1
    if(1 > 0)
    {
      for(batchi in 1:20) 
      {
        anObjectIwantToCreate <- foreach( qrc = 1:100, .combine=c ) %do% 
        {
          return(runif(1)) # I know this is not efficient, it is a placeholder to reproduce the issue
        }
        aRandomCounter = aRandomCounter + sum(anObjectIwantToCreate > 0.5)
      } 
    }
    return(aRandomCounter)
  }
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Replacing the inner `foreach` with a simple `for` or `(l/s)apply` is a solution. But is there a way to make this work with the inner `foreach` and why the error in the first place ?

Comment: It is considered exceptionally rude to embed a `rm(list=ls())` statement in code posted on SO. Someone who is trying to help you might accidentally wipe out their whole session, which could take hours to rebuild. This is why I commented it out. Do not do this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, I got it to work as soon as I posted it (sorry.. I will leave it in case someone else has the same issue). It is a scoping issue - I knew you had to load any external packages within the `%dopar%`, but what I did not realize is that that includes the `foreach` package itself. Here is the solution:

```
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
cl<-makeCluster(5) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
for(stepi in 1:10)  # normal outer for
{
  foreach(rc=1:5) %dopar% # the time consuming stuff in parallel (not looking to actually retrieve any data)
  {
    require(foreach) ### the solution
    aRandomCounter = -1
    if(1 > 0) 
    {
      for(batchi in 1:20) 
      {
        anObjectIwantToCreate <- foreach( qrc = 1:100, .combine=c ) %do% 
        {
          return(runif(1))
        }
        aRandomCounter = aRandomCounter + sum(anObjectIwantToCreate > 0.5)
      } 
    }
    return(aRandomCounter)
  }
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You can also use `foreach(rc=1:5, .packages="foreach") %dopar% ...`. In other words you can identify necessary packages using the `.packages=...` argument, without using `require(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

- I know this is an outdate question, but just to give a hint for those
  who do not get nested foreach to work.
- If parallelizing outer loop with putting `%do% in %dopar%`, you would
  need to include `.packages = c("doSNOW")` in the augment of the
  outer loop (%dopar%), otherwise you will run into `"doSNOW not found"` error.
- Generally, people just parallelize inner loop (%dopar% in %:%), which
  can be slow for a huge amount of data (waiting for combinations of inner loops).